# Change navsection background for each page route nextjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, tailwind-css, react-query

I am creating a NextJs app and have a homepage and routes to the products and about pages and would like to fetch a different header image for each component's Nav section. The image is to be loaded from an API when a user navigates to each page. How can I possibly be able to achieve this even when using images from my file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `useLocation()` hook . The `pathname` object of this hook returns the path name you are at like `/`,`/about` etc.

So use like this

```
import {    useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

.
.
.
const { pathname } = useLocation();
.
.
```

Now if you have pathname, so you can use `if stmts` like this

```
  if( pathname === '/') {
    headerimage_src = '/image1.png'; }
  else if( pathname === '/about') {
    headerimage_src = '/image2.png'; }
 .
 .
 .
```

and then use this value where you are adding header image in DOM.

Comment: The idea is correct, but Next.js has its own built-in [`next/router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router). You'd want to use that instead, e.g. `const { pathname } = useRouter()`.

Comment: Sure go ahead with useRouter